# combine Rust nested Result match arms with the same Error case

Tags: rust, error-handling, pattern-matching

I am attempting to work with nested `match` arms, both handling the `Err` case with the same code.

This seems quite repetitive, and if there were further parsing and unwrapping to be done it would get even worse.

Is there a way to let the `Err` case from the inner arm "bubble up" to the outer one, or otherwise apply the same error handling to those multiple different, possibly nested `Err` cases?

```rust
pub fn get_content_length(
    headers: axum::http::HeaderMap,
) -> Result<usize, (axum::http::StatusCode, String)> {
    let content_length = match headers.get("content-length") {
        Some(header_val) => match header_val.to_str() {
            Ok(header_val) => match header_val.parse::<usize>() {
                Ok(content_length) => content_length,
                Err(e) => {
                    return Err((
                        axum::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                        format!("error parsing header content-length: {}", e.to_string()),
                    ))
                }
            },
            Err(e) => {
                return Err((
                    axum::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                    format!("error parsing header content-length: {}", e.to_string()),
                ))
            }
        },
        None => {
            return Err((
                axum::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                String::from("missing content-length header"),
            ))
        }
    };
    Ok(content_length)
}
```

Comment: You can use [`Result.map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) in conjuntion with `?` to early return the error. Also [`Option.ok_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or_else) for the `Option` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are of different type, so you cannot do that. But since all you want is to display them, you can convert them to strings:

```rust
pub fn get_content_length(
    headers: axum::http::HeaderMap,
) -> Result<usize, (axum::http::StatusCode, String)> {
    let content_length = match headers.get("content-length") {
        Some(header_val) => match header_val
            .to_str()
            .map_err(|e| e.to_string())
            .and_then(|header_val| header_val.parse::<usize>().map_err(|e| e.to_string()))
        {
            Ok(content_length) => content_length,
            Err(e) => {
                return Err((
                    axum::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                    format!("error parsing header content-length: {}", e.to_string()),
                ))
            }
        },
        None => {
            return Err((
                axum::http::StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST,
                String::from("missing content-length header"),
            ))
        }
    };
    Ok(content_length)
}
```

Comment: this accomplishes what I was looking for - I was imagining a generic function applied to both error types, but this is very straightforward and only has to apply the transform to HTTP response once.
The final `e.to_string` isn't needed since they're already converted there